# Finding the count of the total amount of rows that meet criteria in array | Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, codable

Essentially I have a tableview with rows that are populated using JSON with the following structure:

```
struct Section {
    let name : String
    var items : [Portfolio]
}

struct Portfolio: Decodable {

    let person: String
    let number: String
    var checking: Int

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case customer, serial, checking
    }

}
```

The value of checking can either be 1 or 0

How can I get a count of the total number of rows that have checking = 1?

Currently I am trying to do something like this but I'm not sure if this is heading in the right direction:

```
let item = sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
let a = item.checking
let count = a.filter({ $0 % 2 == 0 }).count
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need (if for all sections )

```
let total = sections.map { $0.items.filter { $0.checking == 1 }.count }.reduce(0,+)
```

if for a specific section

```
let total = sections[indexpath.section].items.filter { $0.checking == 1 }.count
```

Comment: Thank you, if you don't mind there is one more question that I cannot resolve. I would appreciate your help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61625246/including-number-of-rows-within-a-section-as-part-of-the-header-title-swift

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it

```
func totalItems(_ sections: [Section]) -> Int {
  return sections.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.items.filter{ $0.checking == 1 }.count }
}
```