# Section header title with number of rows within section | Swift

Tags: swift

Essentially I have a tableview with rows that are populated using JSON with the following structure:

```
struct Section {
    let name : String
    var items : [Portfolio]
}

struct Portfolio: Decodable {

    let person: String
    let number: String
    var checking: Int

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case number, number, checking
    }

}
```

Currently the name being populated in each section is only the value of `person` in portfolio but I would also like it to include the number of rows in EACH section as part of title header of each section.

For example right now it says "Jake" as the title on the header for one of the sections, but I would like it to say "1 - Jake" if for that `person` there was 1 row in that section

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let section = sections[section]

    return section.items.count

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

   return sections[section].name

}
```

Can something like this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
            return "\(section + 1) - \(sections[section].name)"

    }
```

Comment: Not quite, I would like to display the amount of rows in a section as part of the section title. This does not do that.

Comment: sorry I misunderstand, instead of (section + 1 ) put the count of rows array

Comment: Can you please show how this can be done? I haven't implemented this before

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return "\(sections[section].items.count) - \(sections[section].name)"
    }